# how to display the result using jquery and html

Tags: jquery

i want to show the result value in result field.

```
    $('.calc').change(function(){
        var total = 0;
        $('.calc').each(function(){
            if($(this).val() != '')
            {
                total += parseInt($(this).val());
            }
        });
        $('.total').html(total);
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Here is HTML

```
    <td>First:</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="calc" value=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Second:</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="calc" value=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Result:</td>
    <td><input type="text" id=""></td>
```

Comment: so what is the probelm

Comment: please edit your initial post rather than adding a comment

Comment: the result did not show up, what should I do to the input field?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your result element don't have the class `result` with which you are trying to access that element.

Also to set an input element's value you need to use .val()

```js
var $els = $('.calc').change(function() {
  var total = 0;
  $els.each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() != '') {
      total += parseInt($(this).val()) || 0;
    }
  });
  $('.total').val(total);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>First:</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="calc" value="" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Second:</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="calc" value="" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Result:</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="total" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```